# Regular expression to split greedy but keep split token?

Tags: regex, postfix-notation

I have a string like:

```
{A}{B}={C}{D}<{E}{F}<=
```

What I want to do is split that string using a regular expression so as to get something like:

```
1: {A}{B}=
2: {C}{D}<
3: {E}{F}<=
```

I'm currently splitting the string using `(?<=\>)|(?<=\<\=)|(?<=\>\=)|(?<=\=)|(?<=\<)|(?<=!\=)` but it's not producing the desired result, as you can see:

```
1: {A}{B}=
2: {C}{D}<
3: {E}{F}<
4: =
```

What do I need to change in the regular expression to get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(?<=<=)|(?<=>=)|(?<=!=)|(?<==(?!=))|(?<=<(?!=))|(?<=>(?!=))
```

Or use match instead of split with this simpler regular expression:

```
.*?(?:<=|>=|!=|=|<|>)
```